# Rails CSV import - association params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, associations

I am trying to figure out how to import a CSV file to create new records and make the appropriate associations.

I have 3 models:
1) **Farmer** (has_many :farms)
2) **Farm** (has_many :crops, belongs_to :farmer) 
3) **Crop** (belongs_to :farm)

The goal is to have the user create each farm manually, and then import the crops though a CSV file. I cannot figure out how to pass the farm_id to the crops getting uploaded, creating the association.

The import action on the Crops controller:

```
def import
  Crop.import(params[:file], params[:farm_id])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Crops imported."
end
```

The import method in the Crop model:

```
    def self.import(file, farm)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|
        row["farm_id"] = farm
        Crop.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
```

The form for the upload on the farms#show page:

```
#@farm = Farm.find(params[:id])
<%= form_tag import_crops_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "import CSV" %>
```

How do you send over the @farm.id on the farms#show page to import#crops along with the file?
 Is it best to do this through the form - or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a couple ways, it depends on how your routes are set up.

If you have something like

```
resources :farms do
  resources :crops
end
```

import_crops_path(@farm, @crop) will generate a url along the lines of /farms/:farm_id/crops/new

with both options you can get the farm id with params[:farm_id]

Another option is to use a hidden field.

```
f.hidden_field(:farm, :id)
```

this will create a html field

```
<input type="hidden" id="farm_id" name"farm[id]" value="#{@farm.id}" />
```

With both options you can get the farm id with params[:farm_id]

References

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Jon, thank you - This was a routing issue that your suggested nesting fixed. My only concern now is that I am nesting too many things. Is this a bad practice? `resources :farms do 
    resources :crops do 
      collection { post :import }
    end 
  end`